# Combinatorics (Determinant)

Tags: combinatorics

Let f be a function defined on $Z \times Z$. Let
$B=(f(i,j))^r_{i,j=1}$ and $I_r$ the $r\times r$ identity matrix.
Prove that det$ (I_r + B)= \sum_{(a_1,...,a_m)\subseteq (1,2,..,r)}
det(f(a_i,a_j))^m_{i,j=1}$

Here , the sum is over all subsets ${a_1,...,a_m}$ of ${1,2,...,r}$ .If the subset is empty, i.e., $m=0$,
We use the convention that the summand $det(f(a_i,a_j))^0_{i,j=1}$ is 1.
Help me to prove this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use Leibniz identity i.e., $$det(A)=\sum _{\sigma \in S_n}(-1)^{|Inv(\sigma)|}\prod _{i\in [n]}a_{i,\sigma _i},$$
where $Inv(\sigma )=\{(i,j):i<j\wedge\sigma _j<\sigma _i\}.$
 It is clear that you are adding $1's$ where the permutations have fixed points, hence you get something like this:
$$det(I+A)=\sum _{\sigma \in S_n}(-1)^{|Inv(\sigma)|}\prod _{i\in [n]\setminus Fix(\sigma)}a_{i,\sigma _i}\prod _{i\in Fix(\sigma )}(1+a_{i,\sigma _{i}}),$$
where $Fix(\sigma)=\{i\in [n]:\sigma _i = i\}$. Now given $A\subset [n]$ use that $$\{\sigma\in S_n:A\subset Fix(\sigma)\}=S_{n-|A|},$$ the last is a bijection by removing $A$ from $[n]$ and you will have to make just an argument on the sign of the permutations, see that taking out fix points doesnt change the sign of a permutation. In other words if $\sigma_x=x$ then $(-1)^{|Inv(\sigma)|}=(-1)^{|Inv(\sigma _{|[n]\setminus \{x\}})|}.$